# can't install emacs el-get package, emacs can't connect to the internet

Tags: windows, plugins, emacs

I've copied this to my init.el:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path ".emacs.d/el-get/el-get")
(unless (require 'el-get nil t)
  (url-retrieve
   "https://raw.github.com/dimitri/el-get/master/el-get-install.el"
   (lambda (s)
     (end-of-buffer)
     (eval-print-last-sexp))))
```

I'm starting emacs with this code from d:.emacs.d directory that is not in default location

```
set HOME=%~dp0\..
cd ..
D:\emacs-24.3\bin\runemacs.exe --debug-init --xrm "emacs.Background: light green"
```

And this should download the package from github, but instead I get this:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Could not create connection to raw.github.com:443")
signal(error ("Could not create connection to raw.github.com:443"))
error("Could not create connection to %s:%d" "raw.github.com" 443)
url-http([cl-struct-url "https" nil nil "raw.github.com" nil "/dimitri/el-get/master/el-get-install.el" nil nil t nil t] (lambda (s) (end-of-buffer) (eval-print-last-sexp)) (nil))
url-https([cl-struct-url "https" nil nil "raw.github.com" nil "/dimitri/el-get/master/el-get-install.el" nil nil t nil t] (lambda (s) (end-of-buffer) (eval-print-last-sexp)) (nil))
url-retrieve-internal("https://raw.github.com/dimitri/el-get/master/el-get-install.el" (lambda (s) (end-of-buffer) (eval-print-last-sexp)) (nil) nil nil)
url-retrieve("https://raw.github.com/dimitri/el-get/master/el-get-install.el" (lambda (s) (end-of-buffer) (eval-print-last-sexp)))
(if (require (quote el-get) nil t) nil (url-retrieve "https://raw.github.com/dimitri/el-get/master/el-get-install.el" (function (lambda (s) (end-of-buffer) (eval-print-last-sexp)))))
eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "d:/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1831
load-with-code-conversion("d:/.emacs.d/init.el" "d:/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
load("d:/.emacs.d/init" t t)
#[0 "\205\262
```

There is no notice from firewall if emacs is actually trying to connect.

Comment: Do you use a proxy? It is possible that Emacs doesn't know how to read the system proxy configuration on Windows. Try setting the `https_proxy` environment variable with `set https_proxy=PROXY_URL_HERE` before running Emacs.

Comment: No I do not use proxy. And found successfull to use defauld package manager, it downloads definitions without issue.

Answer (score 5):

The [Installation on Windows](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get/wiki/Installation-on-Windows) page that I recently wrote seems like the answer to this question:

> Emacs doesn't support https out of the box on Windows. As mentioned
>   [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs-gnutls/Help-For-Users.html), the needed dlls can be retrieved from
>   http://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/.
>
> - Extract the `dll`s in `bin` from `gnutls-3.0.9-w32-bin.zip` into Emacs' `bin/`
>
>   - but **not** the .exe files, otherwise you might hit [emacs bug 15905](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=15905).
> - You will need to restart Emacs so it can notice the new dlls.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is over a year old, but it still seems very relevant to newer el-get users...

I've not had a lot of success with el-get downloading from that code either (like the website says), but I did use the code from https://github.com/dimitri/el-get and installed it via git clone first, then once I did that, the code in my ~/.emacs.d/init.el (similar to yours above) was working to keep el-get synced.

I would recommend investigating it if you have the desire -- I found that el-get was so much better than native Package.el, mostly because it supports installation of git repos directly, without having to clone them first. (And once it was working through a corporate proxy, it became even more valuable!)